# Verifying the last Two Moore-Penrose Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

If A is an m x n matrix with rank(A) = n, then $A^{+} = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$.
I already proved the first two of the Moore-Penrose equations.  The second two are to verify:

3) $(AA^{+})^{*} = AA^{+}$
4) $(A^{+}A)^{*} = A^{+}A$

I've attempted substituting for $A^{+}$ on one side and moving different matrices around trying to derive the opposite side, but I'm lost outside of those first two moves.

Comment: All you need to know for this is $(AB)^{*} = B^{*}A^{*}$. Note further that you transcribed the first equation incorrectly. I mention only in case this is the source of your troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is really easy to verify: note that $A^+A = (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top A = I$.

For the first equation, recall these identities
\begin{align*}
(AB)^\top &= B^\top A^\top \\
(A^{-1})^\top &= (A^\top)^{-1} \\
(A^\top)^\top &= A.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
(A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top)^\top &= (A^\top)^\top ((A^\top A)^{-1})^\top A^\top \\
&= A ((A^\top A)^\top)^{-1} A^\top \\
&= A (A^\top (A^\top)^\top)^{-1} A^\top \\
&= A (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top.
\end{align*}

Comment: How does proving that $A^{+}A = I$ verify the 3rd Moore-Penrose equation?

Comment: It doesn't; It verifies the fourth equation (if $A$ is not invertible, there will be infinitely many left-inverses). The calculation at the end verifies that $AA^+$ is symmetric.

Comment: Apologies, yes 4th equation.  I am slowly grasping your reasoning.  Was I wrong to assume from the beginning that the RHS must equal the LHS for verification to pass?

Comment: No, you were right. You're verifying the equation holds for the given $A$ and (proposed) $A^+$, so substituting them into both sides should produce the same matrix. I'm not really sure where your doubt is coming from on this point.